# undefined method when trying to build db with activerecord-postgis-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, postgis, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to deploy a rails application using activerecord-postgis-adapter to heroku, however I keep getting this error.

ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]

Rails 3.2.13

```
$ heroku run rake db:schema:load
Running `rake db:schema:load` attached to terminal... up, run.9233
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
-- create_table("active_admin_comments", {:force=>true})

...

-- create_table("locations", {:force=>true})
rake aborted!
undefined method `spatial' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition:0x007f6051920618>
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rgeo-activerecord-0.5.0/lib/rgeo/active_record/common_adapter_elements.rb:107:in `method_missing'
/app/db/schema.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:160:in `create_table'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/app/db/schema.rb:80:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/schema.rb:50:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/schema.rb:50:in `define'
/app/db/schema.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:402:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 3):

As a temporary fix I simply changed `DATABASE_URL` by replacing `postgres://` to `postgis://` as follows:

```
heroku config:set DATABASE_URL='postgis://user:password@host.compute-1.amazonaws.com:port/dbname'
```

This is where I found that work around:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rgeo-users/SDRhEeMZLWc/nue2sFRV6qwJ

I hear it creates other problems in terms of backing up, etc, according to:

https://github.com/dazuma/activerecord-postgis-adapter/issues/14

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I switched to using `unicorn` as my web server. I found that I had to add a special bit of code to `config/unicorn.rb` to make it work:

```
# in config/unicorn.rb
after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['adapter'] = 'postgis'
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

Found the answer here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgis

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue all I had to do was change my adapter in `config/database.yml` to 'postgis' from 'postgresql'.

This was what I was *supposed* to do per my tutorial but I forgot to do it. After than all was well.

Answer (score 1):

So, Heroku Rails will use some database.yml params but not all. For Rails 4.1+ https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior#configuring-connections-in-rails-4-1 states that *adapter* is ignored.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior#active-record-4-1-escape-valve states that it will accept *url* (so that you can host your database somewhere other than Heroku). No need to hardcode it, do a substitution.

`production:
  url: <%= ENV.fetch('DATABASE_URL', '').sub(/^postgres/, "postgis") %>`